# When calling batch files from inside other batch files, only the first one gets called

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file called `dbcompare.bat`, and I use it to run a tool that compares databases. I want to compare a bunch of databases, so I made a second batch file, let's call it `dbcompare-all.bat`, which calls `dbcompare.bat` for each database in turn.

My problem is that when I run `dbcompare-all.bat`, only the first database is compared; the other calls to `dbcompare.bat` don't seem to execute. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Here's the `dbcompare-all.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem syntax: dbcompare-all.bat sa password123
dbcompare.bat system db1 %1 %2
dbcompare.bat system db2 %1 %2
dbcompare.bat system db3 %1 %2
dbcompare.bat system db4 %1 %2
dbcompare.bat system db5 %1 %2
dbcompare.bat system db6 %1 %2
```

And here's the `dbcompare.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem syntax: dbcompare.bat system dbname sa password123
echo Platform is %1
echo Partner DB is %2
echo DB username is %3
sqlpackage /Action:Script /DeployReportPath:%1.%2.xml /DeployScriptPath:%1.%2.sql /TargetDatabaseName:%2 /TargetPassword:%4 /TargetServerName:%1.ourcompanyname.us /TargetUser:%3 /SourceFile:%1.dacpac > %1.%2.out.txt 2> %1.%2.err.txt
```

Comment: Fun Fact: you used the word `call` (called calling, calls) exactly six times. That's exactly the number of times you have to use the `call` command (see @Magoo's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in your question title.

You are `executing` the batch file which transfers execution to the destination batch. When *that* batch ends, the entire process ends.

You need to `do` what you claim to do:

```
CALL dbcompare.bat system db1 %1 %2
CALL dbcompare.bat system db2 %1 %2
CALL dbcompare.bat system db3 %1 %2
...
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. I remember VB also has a Call command, but it doesn't seem to actually do anything; the subroutine being called will return whether or not you use it.